# Error when building EOS from source

Tags: development

I've tried to build eos from source code and I get the error message below :

> [ 83%] Generating dice.abi.hpp [ 84%] Building CXX object
>   libraries/fc/CMakeFiles/fc.dir/src/crypto/elliptic_secp256k1.cpp.o In
>   file included from
>   /Users/Tam/Projects/BlockChain/eos/libraries/fc/src/crypto/elliptic_impl_priv.cpp:5:
>   /Users/Tam/Projects/BlockChain/eos/libraries/fc/src/crypto/_elliptic_impl_priv.hpp:11:7:
>   error: unknown
>         type name 'secp256k1_context_t'; did you mean 'secp256k1_context'? const secp256k1_context_t* _get_context();
>         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         secp256k1_context /usr/local/include/secp256k1.h:43:41: note: 'secp256k1_context' declared here typedef struct
>   secp256k1_context_struct secp256k1_context;
>                                           ^ /Users/Tam/Projects/BlockChain/eos/libraries/fc/src/crypto/elliptic_impl_priv.cpp:52:5:
>   error: unknown type
>         name 'rivate_key'; did you mean 'private_key'?
>       rivate_key private_key::regenerate( const fc::sha256& secret )
>       ^~~~~~~~~~
>       private_key /Users/Tam/Projects/BlockChain/eos/libraries/fc/include/fc/crypto/elliptic.hpp:93:11:
>   note: 'private_key'
>         declared here
>       class private_key

I have tried build and install secp256k1 from bitcoin-core but it did not work. I wonder which version of secp256k1 is using.
Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: The eosio_build.sh script works for me.

Comment: Thank you Lonkly. It is exactly solved my problem. I think it should be documented.

Comment: It is: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/autobuild-script

Answer (score 1):

Please try doing it this way and let us know what happens?

```
git clone https://github.com/cryptonomex/secp256k1-zkp.git  
cd secp256k1-zkp
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```